# Fastlane iOS Suddenly getting error: muninitialized constant Fastlane::Actions::SharedValues::KEYCHAIN_PATH

Tags: ios, build, fastlane

I have fastline set up in AZURE cloud which worked great until a week ago
Suddenly all build are failing, and this is AFTER i set up new FASTLANE_SESSION which i usually do every month

```
getting error: muninitialized constant Fastlane::Actions::SharedValues::KEYCHAIN_PATH
```

fastlane output:

stack trace and command, used

````
 2021-01-28T10:17:33.7609670Z /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
2021-01-28T10:17:33.7629520Z /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118: warning: Pathname#untaint is deprecated and will be removed in Ruby 3.2.
2021-01-28T10:17:33.7630880Z [10:17:33]: [33mGet started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile[0m
2021-01-28T10:17:36.2135810Z [10:17:36]: [33mGenerating fastlane environment output, this might take a few seconds...[0m
2021-01-28T10:17:36.4575750Z ðŸš« fastlane environment ðŸš«
 
 ### Stack
 
 | Key                         | Value                                            |
 | --------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------ |
 | OS                          | 10.15.7                                          |
 | Ruby                        | 3.0.0                                            |
 | Bundler?                    | false                                            |
 | Git                         | git version 2.30.0                               |
 | Installation Source         | ~/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/bin/fastlane    |
 | Host                        | Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H114)                        |
 | Ruby Lib Dir                | ~/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib             |
 | OpenSSL Version             | OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020                       |
 | Is contained                | false                                            |
 | Is homebrew                 | false                                            |
 | Is installed via Fabric.app | false                                            |
 | Xcode Path                  | /Applications/Xcode_12.3.app/Contents/Developer/ |
 | Xcode Version               | 12.3                                             |
 
 
 ### System Locale
 
 | Variable | Value       |   |
 | -------- | ----------- | - |
 | LANG     | en_US.UTF-8 | âœ… |
 | LC_ALL   | en_US.UTF-8 | âœ… |
 | LANGUAGE |             |   |
 
 
 ### fastlane files:
 
 `./fastlane/Fastfile`
 
 ```ruby
 #dont send info to google
 opt_out_usage # opt-out of metrics collection
 default_platform(:ios)
 #xcversion(version: "11.1")
 xcode_select("/Applications/Xcode_12.app")
 
 
 platform :ios do
 
 
 
     desc "Ios build "
     lane :release do |options|
             opt_out_usage # opt-out of metrics collection
             debug
    
             #@my_key_name = ENV['IPHONE_DISTRIBUTION']
         
         
            project_name = options[:projectName]
            app_identifier = options[:appIdentifier]
            v_num = options[:versionNumber]
            build_number = options[:buildNumber]
            ftp_path = options[:plistFileFtpBasePath]
            ArtifactsDirectory = options[:ArtifactsDirectory]
            
             create_keychain(
                 name: ENV['IPHONE_DISTRIBUTION'],
                 default_keychain: true,
                 unlock: true,
                 timeout: false,
                 password: ENV['CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD'])
 
             import_certificate(
                 certificate_path: ENV['CERTIFICATE_PATH_P12'],
                 certificate_password: ENV['CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD'],
                 keychain_name: ENV['IPHONE_DISTRIBUTION'],
                 keychain_password: ENV['CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD'],
                 log_output: true)
 
             import_certificate(
                 certificate_path: ENV['CERTIFICATE_PATH_CER'],
                 keychain_name: ENV['IPHONE_DISTRIBUTION'],
                 log_output: true)
                
 
            increment_version_number(version_number: v_num)
            bundle_name = "#{project_name}_#{build_number}"
            bundle_version = "#{v_num}_#{build_number}"
            update_info_plist(
                    plist_path:"xxxridxxxnetics/Info.plist",
                    block: proc do |plist|
                            plist[:CFBundleVersion] = bundle_version
                            plist[:CFBundleDisplayName] = bundle_name
                    end
            )
            
            
             
            sigh(
                    username: ENV['APPLE_ID'],
                    app_identifier: app_identifier,
                    team_id: ENV['TEAM_ID']
 
            )
            
            profile_name_found = lane_context[SharedValues::SIGH_NAME]
            update_code_signing_settings(profile_name: profile_name_found)
            
            update_code_signing_settings(profile_name: profile_name_found)
            
            automatic_code_signing(code_sign_identity:"iPhone Distribution", use_automatic_signing: false)
 
            #to update PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER, use:
            update_app_identifier(
                xcodeproj: "Hybridxxxnetics.xcodeproj",
                plist_path: "Hybridxxxnetics/Info.plist",
                app_identifier: app_identifier
            )
            
 
            build_app(
                  workspace: "Hybridxxxnetics.xcworkspace",
                  output_name:"#{project_name}_#{v_num}_#{build_number}.ipa",
                  output_directory:"#{ArtifactsDirectory}",
                  export_options: {
                        manifest: {
                                appURL: "#{ftp_path}/#{project_name}_#{v_num}_#{build_number}.ipa",
                                displayImageURL: "https://download.xxxnetics.com/release/product-qa/ios/Test/xxxPush57.png",
                                fullSizeImageURL: "https://download.xxxnetics.com/release/product-qa/ios/Test/xxxPush512.png"
                        }
                  }
           )
          
 
     end
 end
 ```
 
 
 `./fastlane/Appfile`
 
 ```ruby
 #app_identifier("com.xxxnetics.xxxBPEREnt")
 #apple_id("devops@xxxnetics.com")
 #itc_team_id("433380") # App Store Connect Team ID
 #team_id("5E6D333C5B") # Developer Portal Team ID```
 
 
 ### fastlane gems
 
 | Gem      | Version | Update-Status      |
 | -------- | ------- | ------------------ |
 | fastlane | 2.54.1  | ðŸš« Update available |
 
 
 ### Loaded fastlane plugins:
 
 **No plugins Loaded**
 
 
 Loaded gems
 
 | Gem                       | Version      |
 | ------------------------- | ------------ |
 | did_you_mean              | 1.5.0        |
 | slack-notifier            | 1.5.1        |
 | atomos                    | 0.1.3        |
 | CFPropertyList            | 2.3.6        |
 | claide                    | 1.0.3        |
 | colored2                  | 3.1.2        |
 | nanaimo                   | 0.3.0        |
 | xcodeproj                 | 1.19.0       |
 | rouge                     | 2.0.7        |
 | xcpretty                  | 0.3.0        |
 | terminal-notifier         | 1.8.0        |
 | unicode-display_width     | 1.7.0        |
 | terminal-table            | 1.8.0        |
 | plist                     | 3.6.0        |
 | public_suffix             | 4.0.6        |
 | addressable               | 2.7.0        |
 | multipart-post            | 2.0.0        |
 | word_wrap                 | 1.0.0        |
 | tty-screen                | 0.5.1        |
 | babosa                    | 1.0.4        |
 | colored                   | 1.2          |
 | highline                  | 1.7.10       |
 | commander-fastlane        | 4.4.6        |
 | excon                     | 0.78.1       |
 | faraday                   | 0.17.3       |
 | unf_ext                   | 0.0.7.7      |
 | unf                       | 0.1.4        |
 | domain_name               | 0.5.20190701 |
 | http-cookie               | 1.0.3        |
 | faraday-cookie_jar        | 0.0.7        |
 | fastimage                 | 2.2.1        |
 | gh_inspector              | 1.1.3        |
 | uber                      | 0.1.0        |
 | declarative               | 0.0.20       |
 | declarative-option        | 0.1.0        |
 | representable             | 3.0.4        |
 | retriable                 | 3.1.2        |
 | mini_mime                 | 1.0.2        |
 | jwt                       | 2.2.2        |
 | multi_json                | 1.15.0       |
 | signet                    | 0.14.1       |
 | memoist                   | 0.16.2       |
 | os                        | 1.1.1        |
 | googleauth                | 0.15.0       |
 | httpclient                | 2.8.3        |
 | rexml                     | 3.2.4        |
 | webrick                   | 1.7.0        |
 | google-apis-core          | 0.2.1        |
 | gems                      | 1.2.0        |
 | google-apis-discovery_v1  | 0.1.0        |
 | thor                      | 1.1.0        |
 | google-apis-generator     | 0.1.2        |
 | google-api-client         | 0.53.0       |
 | json                      | 2.5.1        |
 | mini_magick               | 4.5.1        |
 | multi_xml                 | 0.6.0        |
 | rubyzip                   | 1.3.0        |
 | security                  | 0.1.3        |
 | xcpretty-travis-formatter | 1.0.1        |
 | dotenv                    | 2.7.6        |
 | bundler                   | 1.17.3       |
 | faraday_middleware        | 0.14.0       |
 | tsort                     | 0.1.0        |
 | set                       | 1.0.1        |
 | uri                       | 0.10.1       |
 | minitest                  | 5.14.2       |
 | zeitwerk                  | 2.4.2        |
 | concurrent-ruby           | 1.1.8        |
 | tzinfo                    | 2.0.4        |
 | i18n                      | 1.8.7        |
 | activesupport             | 6.1.1        |
 | ostruct                   | 0.3.1        |
 | logger                    | 1.4.3        |
 | cgi                       | 0.2.0        |
 | erb                       | 2.2.0        |
 | strscan                   | 3.0.0        |
 | optparse                  | 0.1.0        |
 | stringio                  | 3.0.0        |
 | abbrev                    | 0.1.0        |
 | date                      | 3.1.0        |
 | pathname                  | 0.1.0        |
 | forwardable               | 1.3.2        |
 | tempfile                  | 0.1.1        |
 | delegate                  | 0.2.0        |
 | fileutils                 | 1.5.0        |
 | tmpdir                    | 0.1.1        |
 | shellwords                | 0.1.0        |
 | openssl                   | 2.2.0        |
 | io-nonblock               | 0.1.0        |
 | ipaddr                    | 1.2.2        |
 | io-wait                   | 0.1.0        |
 | timeout                   | 0.1.1        |
 | zlib                      | 1.1.0        |
 | digest                    | 3.0.0        |
 | time                      | 0.1.0        |
 | open-uri                  | 0.1.0        |
 | singleton                 | 0.1.1        |
 | base64                    | 0.1.0        |
 | prettyprint               | 0.1.0        |
 | pp                        | 0.1.0        |
 | open3                     | 0.1.1        |
 | net-protocol              | 0.1.0        |
 | net-smtp                  | 0.2.1        |
 | securerandom              | 0.1.0        |
 | english                   | 0.7.1        |
 | find                      | 0.1.0        |
 | etc                       | 1.2.0        |
 | resolv                    | 0.2.0        |
 
 
 
 *generated on:* **2021-01-28**
 
 [10:17:36]: [32mOpen https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/new to submit a new issue âœ…[0m
 [10:17:36]: Sending Crash/Success information
 [10:17:36]: Learn more at https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane#metrics
 [10:17:36]: No xxxnal/sensitive data is sent. Only sharing the following:
 [10:17:36]: {:fastlane=>1}
 [10:17:36]: This information is used to fix failing tools and improve those that are most often used.
 [10:17:36]: You can disable this by adding `opt_out_usage` at the top of your Fastfile
 
 [32m#######################################################################[0m
 [32m# fastlane 2.172.0 is available. You are on 2.54.1.[0m
 [32m# You should use the latest version.[0m
 [32m# Please update using `sudo gem install fastlane`.[0m
 [32m#######################################################################[0m
 
 [32m2.172.0 Big Improvements[0m
 * [frameit] add support for new iPhone 12-family devices and their new colors (#17940) via Nicolas Mauri
 * [deliver][download_metadata] give precedence to generate metadata from edit version instead of live version (#17813) via Roger Oba
 * [action] git_commit - skip commit if git status is clean for paths (#17913) via Pierre Felgines
 * [spaceship][docs] update spaceship app store connect docs (#17938) via Roger Oba
 [snapshot] fix snapshot not saving image files on Apple Silicon M1 (#17912) via Martin Albrecht
 * [fastlane] add BUDDY environment variables (#17922) via RafaÅ‚ Sztwiorok
 * [spaceship] adding missing localizations attribute to AppStoreVersion (#17928) via gsavit
 * Update sample issue from being an existing issue, to a fake one. (#17934) via Roger Oba
 * [action] swiftlint - avoid throwing error for new types of reporters. (#17935) via Roger Oba
 * [action] change 'platform' optionality since nil is not really a valid value. (#17936) via Roger Oba
 * [gym] update gym's available export_methods to match xcodebuild's. (#17939) via Roger Oba
 * [frameit] fix the screenshot size of iPhone 8 Plus (#17977) via Rhett Tuan
 * [action] register_device - fix regression that was causing a crash when creating a device that already exists (#17799) via Roger Oba
 * [spaceship] allow 2FA request only in interactive mode (#17854) via Oleg Kohtenko
 * [action] new create_xcframework action (#17844) via JosÃ© GonzÃ¡lez
 * [CI] support Ruby 2.7 on Circle CI (#17861) via Satoshi Namai
 * [action] artifactory - add option to authenticate using an API key (#17835) via Florian Staine
 * [gym] update identifier used to looked up the bundle ID when parsing provisioning profile (#17865) via John Britton
 * [spaceship] allow for updating of beta groups (#17984) via Krish
 * [snapshot] fix picking up 'SnapshotHelper'-files from DerivedData #17828 (#17833) via David EverlÃ¶f
 * [gym] use unzip for IPA files that are too big (#17825) via Theodore Dubois
 * [action] change username for register_devices action to optional (#17942) via Econa77
 * [action] add api bearer to create pull request (#17972) via Thilek Silvadorai
 * [scan] fix scan not failing when disable_xcpretty and fail_build are true (#17946) via Jean Mainguy
 * [scan] fix scan regression caused by not setting `slack_default_payloads` option (#17923) via Roger Oba
 * [gym][scan][snapshot] disable automatic SPM dependencies resolution or skip it entirely (#17916) via Roman Tysiachnik
 * [gym][snapshot] fix gym `use_system_scm` option and add `use_system_scm` option to snapshot (#17832) via Roger Oba
 
 [32m2.171.0 Improvements and Goodbye 2020[0m
 * [itunes-transporter] fix transporter `DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS` env var validation (#17793) via Roger Oba
 * [action] push_to_git_remote - add `--push-options` option to `push_to_git_remote` action (#17791) via Roger Oba
 * [action] pod_push - add `use_json` parameter to `pod_push` action (#17809) via JosÃ© GonzÃ¡lez
 * [action] spm - add `--enable-code-coverage` option to `spm` action `test` command (#17805) via Andrea Sacerdoti
 * [action] git_commit - skip commit if nothing is staged (#17804) via Pierre Felgines
 * [action] add_git_tag - add option to omit the current lane from tag and message (#17792) via Roger Oba
 * [actions] github action - add Bearer authentication option (#17764) via David Cacenabes
 * [precheck] allow precheck to be run on live app versions as well as edit ones (#17738) via Roger Oba
 * [match] fix MATCH_GIT_PRIVATE_KEY ignored on repo push (#17829) via Sascha P
 * [spaceship] adding headers to connect api response object (#17867) via gsavit
 * [scan][slack] add `slack_default_payloads` option to scan and improve slack action's `default_payloads` docs (#17866) via Roger Oba
 * [sigh] fix undefined method `expires` with `expiration_date` in Sigh::Runner (#17741) via Roger Oba
 * [spaceship] adding missing phased release and review details attributes (#17761) via gsavit
 * [action] add `download_app_privacy_details_from_app_store` action (#17746) via Igor Makarov
 * [match] fix recursion when MATCH_PASSWORD is not set (#17557) via Roger Oba
 * [action] fail nexus_upload action when the underlying command line fails. (#17740) via Roger Oba
 * [deliver] correct dependencies (#17739) via Satoshi Namai
 * [screengrab] quickfix for valid locales like en_US in Screengrab (#17555) via Marc PEREZ
 * [deliver] improve screenshot validation (#17708) via Satoshi Namai
 * [tests] fix random test sample code failing test (#17750) via Josh Holtz
 
 [32m2.170.0 Improvements and Upload App Privacy Details[0m
 * [Fastlane.swift] fixed potential undefined method `action_name' in generator (#17660) via phil zhang
 * [action] onesignal - update onesignal.rb to include optional organization_id (#17696) via Brandon Carpenter
 * [deliver] fix a regression in language detection in Deliver::UploadMetadata (#17730) via Satoshi Namai
 * [action] NEW ACTION for App Data Usages: upload_app_privacy_details_to_app_store (#17592) via Josh Holtz
 * [match] only include enabled devices for force_for_new_devices (#17695) via Steven Roebert
 
 For more information on uploading App Privacy Details, go to https://docs.fastlane.tools/uploading-app-privacy-details/
 
 [32mTo see all new releases, open https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases[0m
 
 [32mPlease update using `sudo gem install fastlane`[0m
 ##[section]Finishing: invoke fastlane And create keychain
````

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I get the "factory" shared values, but I can't use the same syntax to retrieve values from my .env file. Using `ENV['MY_CUSTOM_VALUE']` works. without issue.